# Parsing boolean values from a JSONObject with CheckBoxes in a ListView Adapter

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I have a JSONObject with boolean values and different Strings inside the Object it looks very much like this

```
{"1c1":false,"1c2":false,"1c3":false,"1c4":false,"1ed1":false,"1ed2":false,"1ed3":false,"1ep1":true,"2c1":true,"2c2":true,"2c3":false,"2ed1":false,"2ed2":false,"2ed3":true}
```

Each ListView Item has a value which is equal to at least one of the strings in the JSONObject

**ChecklistAdapter.java**

```
public class ChecklistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Record> {



public ChecklistAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.checklist_item);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.checklist_item, parent, false);

    }

        TextView desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        final JSONObject fetchedJSON = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getJSONObject("checklistData");
        final Record dataRecord = getItem(position);

        desc.setText(dataRecord.getValue());

        final JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();



    // if item id in list view is equal to one of the strings in the json object make sure the checkbox is selected as true


    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        String idSelected = dataRecord.getID();

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

                ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("checklistData", myObject);
                ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), idSelected,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CheckBox is unchecked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;

        }

        public void swapImageRecords(List<Record> objects) {
            clear();

            for (Record object : objects) {
                add(object);
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
```

As seen inside the code when a ListView Item is clicked it returns the selected ID given which is equal to one of the Strings in the JSONObject

```
String idSelected = dataRecord.getID();
```

My plan is if "idSelected" is equal to one of the the strings in the JSONObject check if it's a true or false boolean and have the checkbox selected as a true value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if you need help with the boolean value or syncing the state to the `CheckBox`.

In the case of booleans, you can use the `getBoolean()` method on JSONObject to receive a Java boolean. Below is a link to the documentation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thank's! I'll give the docs a look and see what I can do to sync the state of the Checkbox